# Filtering observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray, computed-observable

I have troubles with filtering observable array with knockout.js

my js:

Array containing data

```
var docListData = [
    { name: "Article Name 1", info: "Authors, name of edition, publishing year,(moreinfo?)", checked:ko.observable(false)  },
    { name: "Article Name 2", info: "Authors, name of edition, publishing year,(moreinfo?)", checked:ko.observable(false) },
    { name: "Article Name 3", info: "Authors, name of edition, publishing year,(moreinfo?)", checked:ko.observable(false) }
];
```

viewmodel:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
```

Filling observable array with data

```
    self.docList = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(docListData, function (item) {
            return item;
        })
    );

self.appendableData = ko.observableArray([]);
```

Creating additional parameters in observable array

```
    for (var i=0; i < self.docList().length; i++){
        self.docList()[i].type = "document";
        self.docList()[i].id = i;
        self.docList()[i].pos = ko.observable(-1);
//        self.docList()[i].pos = -1;
        self.appendableData().push(self.docList()[i]);

    };
```

Function that changes additional values in my observable array and logs changes to console

```
toggleChecked = function (){
    this.checked(!this.checked());
    if (this.checked() === true){
        this.pos = self.position; // changes value, but doesn't affect target array
        self.appendableData()[this.id].pos = self.position; //second try, same result
        self.position++;
        console.log("this.pos",this.pos);
        console.log("this id: ", this.id);            
    } else if(this.checked() === false) {
        this.pos = self.position;
        self.position--;
        console.log("this.pos",this.pos);
        console.log('nope');

    };

    console.log("position for next: ",self.position);
        console.log(self.appendableData());
        console.log(self.appendableDataToView());
};
```

manual changes affect target array

```
    self.appendableData()[2].pos =2; // this affects target array
```

filtering function returns an empty array:

```
    self.appendableDataToView = ko.computed(function () {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.appendableData(), function (item) {
            return item.pos >= 0;
        });
    });
```

my html code:

```
<div class="list-wrapper">
    <ul class="unstyled" data-bind="if: docList().length > 0">
        <li data-bind="foreach: docList">
            <label class="checkbox" data-bind="click: toggleChecked">
                <p data-bind="text: name"></p>
                <span data-bind="text: info"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think that you use `pos` property in wrong way. It's observable so you should assign it in the following way:

```
self.appendableData()[2].pos(2);
```

and in your filter function correct retrieving the value:

```
return item.pos() >= 0;
```

Additionally I suggest you to use knockout-projections library (https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-projections) - it's more efficient:

```
self.appendableDataToView = self.appendableData.fitler(function (item) {
    return item.pos >= 0;
});
```